# How to fold a collection of endomorphism with cats

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats

Given a function

```
def f(i: I) : S => S
```

I would like to write a pretty common combinator `g`

```
def g(is : Seq[I], init: S) : S
```

The easy implementation uses only classic scala

```
def g(is : Seq[I], init: S) : S = 
  is.foldLeft(init){ case (acc, i) => f(i)(acc) }
```

I tried to use `Foldable` but I encountered a compilation issue.

```
import cats._
import cats.Monoid
import cats.implicits._
def g(is : Seq[I], init: S) : S = 
  Foldable[List].foldMap(is.toList)(f _)(init)
```

The error is

```
could not find implicit value for parameter B: cats.Monoid[S => S]
```

I succeeded with `State`

```
import cats.data.State
import cats.instances.all._
import cats.syntax.traverse._

def g(is : Seq[I], init: S) : S = 
  is.toList.map(i => State.modify(f(i))).sequenceU.runS(init).value
```

I have some questions :

1. Is there a `Monoid` for endomorphism in cats
2. Can you explain compilation issue when I use all `import` statements together ? Is there a trick to find the right import easily ?
3. Is `State` a too powerful abstraction in this case ?
4. Is there a better way ?

[update]
I've found a workaround for 1.

```
type Endo[S] = S => S
def g(is : Seq[I], init: S) : S 
  = Foldable[List].foldK[Endo, S](dirs.toList.map(f _))
```

But I still a `foldMapK` to avoid boilerplate …

Comment: You could specify the `Monoid` instance yourself : `Foldable[List].foldMap(is.toList)(f _)(MonoidK[Endo].algebra)(init)`

Answer (score 3):

`foldMap` won't work here because your `f` is `I => S => S`, which doesn't match the signature of `foldMap`:

```
def foldMap[A, B](fa: F[A])(f: (A) ⇒ B)(implicit B: Monoid[B]): B
```

you'll need your `A => B` and `B => B => B` (the `Monoid`) separate. `f` already merged these two operations. Just use `foldLeft`.

Comment: Why B can't be S => S ?

Comment: Sure, but then you'd need `(S => S) => (S => S) => (S => S)`.

Comment: is there any instance of Monoid[S=>S] in cats ?

Comment: Yes. http://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/implicits$.html#catsKernelCommutativeMonoidForFunction1[A,B](implicitM:cats.kernel.CommutativeMonoid[B]):cats.kernel.CommutativeMonoid[A=>B]

Comment: I'm stuck with `catsStdMonoidKForFunction1.algebra.combineAll(is.map(f))(init)`. It works but it's ugly.

Comment: `Monoid[S => S].algebra` might be nicer.

Comment: I got this error :
Error:(22, 65) could not find implicit value for parameter ev: cats.kernel.Monoid[S => S]

Comment: `implicit def endoMonoid[A]: Monoid[A => A] = MonoidK[Endo].algebra`